# How to test the change in color of any hyper link after clicking the link by using selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium, hyperlink, webdriver

When I click on a link on a web page, the color of the hyper link gets changed. How can I test this feature by using selenium web driver.

Comment: Do you mean the way it gets set to purple after it's visited? If so, that depends. I believe the browser handles this most times but it can be overriden with CSS. You'll have to check with your developers to see if they do anything with CSS when it comes to visited links.

Comment: this is an incredibly pedantic thing to test, and is very minimal in scope of usability.. this type of style testing is a huge waste of time.. by the time you figure it out, the return on investment will not be worth it.. Don't test this sort of thing.

Comment: Are you trying to show the change of color when the cursor moves to hyperlink..??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't.

The 'state' (visited or not) of a link is set by the browser. Depending of the 'state' the link appears in one colour or in another. CSS can override the colour used by the browser but not the 'state'. This is not something Selenium can give you access.

Moreover, I agree with sircapsalot, it is a waste of time as you will test if the web browser do its job and not the web page itself.

Comment: same reason you don't test "make sure that this image is 90x90 and in this particular location"